# Aloha editor - Uncaught ReferenceError: Aloha is not defined

Tags: javascript, aloha-editor

So this looks like a completely simple thing that I must be missing, but here goes:

I've been following the guide for Aloha editor, [here](http://aloha-editor.org/builds/development/latest/doc/guides/output/using_aloha.html).

I have included aloha.js in my page (and it is included, it is pulling down all the CSS etc).

I then have this code in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Aloha.ready(function(){
    Aloha.jQuery('textarea.description').aloha();
});
</script>
```

Which throws an uncauht referenceerror.

In the console, GENTICS.Aloha is defined, but Aloha is not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Aloha.ready(function(){
        Aloha.jQuery('.description').aloha();
    });
</script>
```

You only specify the CSS classname as far as I know like shown above.